# Vite: preprocessorOptions not working in vite.config.js

Tags: node.js, vite

I'm trying to preprocessorOptions to vite.config.js:

```
 css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: `
                @import '@/assets/scss/main.scss';
                `,
            },
        },
  },
```

But I can't see the changes. If I move the import to main.js everything works fine, but it doesn't work in vite.config.js. What am I doing wrong? I just checked another project where it works fine the same settings, but here in the new one I don't understand what's the issue. I thought it's a package dependecy version issue, but I installed the same versions as in another projects where everything works and the issue remains. I checked aliases, they also work. Any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a style to any of the classes. For some reason, main.scss styles won't work until you add a style to the class in one of your components.